# Power series convergence (hypergeometric)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the power series $\sum a_nx^n $ where $$a_n = \frac{2.4.6...(2n)}{1.3.5...(2n+1)}$$
Now the ratio test shows absolute convergence for all $|x|<1$ and divergence for $|x|>1$. Also Raabe’s test shows divergence for x=1. The remaining case is for x=-1 which I’m not able to solve. Help will be highly appreciated.(using only basic inequalities/methods. No sterling’s formula etc :) )

Comment: It can be shown that $\frac12\sqrt{\frac\pi{n+1}}\le a_n\le\frac12\sqrt{\frac\pi{n+1/2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series is alternative, so we may consider the Leibniz test. Pretty clear that the series converges for $x =-1$. Could you find out why?

#### UPDATE

To show $a_n\to 0$, one may try prove that [WRONG INEQUALITY]
$$
\frac {(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} < \frac 1{\sqrt {2n+1}}. 
$$

Also the series diverges at $x = 1$ as the OP mentioned by Raabe test.

#### EDIT

Thanks to @robjohn who pointed out the inequality is reversed. It should be 
$$
\frac {(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} < \frac 1{\sqrt {n+1}}. 
$$

Comment: I’m not able to find a bound for a_n

Comment: +1 Alternatively, the series is absolutely convergent, as the $x = 1$ case indicates.

Comment: How will you show an goes to 0?

Comment: @JohnMitchell Sorry about my wrong comment.

Comment: an is certainly decreasing but that does not show it goes to 0.

Comment: For x=1 it diverges right?

Comment: @JohnMitchell UPDATED. Feel free to check.

Comment: This is correct indeed

Comment: Your inequality is backward. However, we do have $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\lt\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$, which does give the same result for the series.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Simple Estimates**

Let
$$
a_n=\frac1{3/2}\frac2{5/2}\cdots\frac{n}{n+1/2}
$$
and
$$
b_n=\frac{3/2}2\frac{5/2}3\cdots\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}
$$
and
$$
c_n=\frac{1/2}1\frac{3/2}2\cdots\frac{n-1/2}{n}
$$
Since $\frac{x}{x+1/2}\lt\frac{x+1/2}{x+1}$, we get
$$
c_n\lt a_n\lt b_n
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{2n+1}=a_nc_n\le a_n^2\le a_nb_n=\frac1{n+1}
$$
This means that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
$$
converges for $-1\le x\lt1$.

---

**Applying More Power**

Since
$$
a_n=\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac32\right)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(1)\,\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac32\right)}
$$
and by the log-convexity of $\Gamma$, we get
$$
\frac12\sqrt{\frac\pi{n+1}}\le a_n\le\frac12\sqrt{\frac\pi{n+1/2}}
$$